# ExtJs get form values of a two column form

Tags: extjs

I have created a form with two columns. In my viewcontroller I would like to access the form values.
Unfortunately I only managed to access the left column. How do I access the values of the right column

```
Ext.define('ocm.view.ocmMask.ModalOverviewOperationsEdit', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    xtype: 'modaloperationedit',
    title: 'Einsatz bearbeiten',
    frame: true,
    resizable: true,
    width: 700,
    minWidth: 700,
    minHeight: 300,
    bodyPadding: 0,
    layout: 'column',
    controller: 'overviewoperations',

    defaults: {
        layout: 'form',
        xtype: 'container',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        style: 'width: 50%'
    },

    items: [{
        //I get the Values of this column
        xtype: 'form',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: BpcCommon.lang.Current.OCM_MASK_DATE,
                maxValue: new Date(),
                bind: "{operation.ALARMIERUNGSDATUM}",
                name: 'ALARMIERUNGSDATUM',
                required: true
            }]
    }, {
        //I didn't get this values
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                store: "ocmKeywordStore",
                valueField:'ID',
                name: "ALLOCATION",
                id: "ALLOCATION",
                fieldLabel: BpcCommon.lang.Current.OCM_MASK_ALLOCATION,
                displayField:'Text',
                queryParam: false,
                editable: false,
            }]
    }],
```

In the view controller I access it as follows

```
Ext.define('ocm.view.ocmMask.OverviewOperationsController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.overviewoperations',

    updateOperation: function(btn){
        var win = btn.up('window'),
            getForm = win.down('form');
        var values = getForm.getValues();

        console.log(values);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that your second field is not inside your form.

Right now you have an `Ext.window.Window` with the `layout` column that contains a form with a datefield and a container that contains a Combobox.

So your `getValues`(https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-getValues) method does the right thing and gives you all values from fields that are contained or inside your form.

I just did a small fiddle. Maybe you more looking for an approach like this?

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/36kq